# How can I clean this string and leave only text (Python)

Tags: python

I have the following string in python:

```
"\n[[[\"guns\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"china chinese spy balloon\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"aris hampers grand rapids\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"mountain lion p 22\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"real estate housing market\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"hunter biden\",46,[143,362,396,357],{\"lm\":[],\"zf\":33,\"zh\":\"Hunter Biden\",\"zi\":\"American attorney\",\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ssp\":\"eJzj4tLP1TcwycrOK88xYPTiySjNK0ktUkjKTEnNAwBulQip\"},\"zs\":\"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\\u003dtbn:ANd9GcQaO4eyFc6sDCa7A26Y_9g71clgC0Ot11Elt0KxAFiQo0Ey7Tp69FWxS8o\\u0026s\\u003d10\"}],[\"maui firefighter tre evans dumaran\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"pope francis benedict\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"coast guard rescue stolen boat\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"lauren boebert\",46,[143,362,396,357],{\"lm\":[],\"zf\":33,\"zh\":\"Lauren Boebert\",\"zi\":\"United States Representative\",\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ssp\":\"eJzj4tVP1zc0zDIqMzCrMCswYPTiy0ksLUrNU0jKT01KLSoBAJDsCeg\"},\"zs\":\"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\\u003dtbn:ANd9GcS1qLJyZQJkVxsOTuP4gnADPLG5oBWe0LWSFClElzhcVrwVCfnNa_s64Zs\\u0026s\\u003d10\"}]],{\"ag\":{\"a\":{\"8\":[\"Trending searches\"]}}}"
```

how can I clean it using python so that it only outputs the text:

"guns",
"china chinese spy balloon",
"aris hampers grand rapids",
"mountain lion p 22",
....

Comment: Looks like the re module would be useful here, particularly groups. I'd start by identifying strings that define the text you want to extract (e.g. it looks like your text is surrounded by "[\"" and "\"", and then set up an appropriate template.

Comment: Decent spot for regexp

Comment: Things you might normally use to parse this are complaining about unbalanced brackets. Is it missing a ] at the end?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what format was used to produce that string.

Comment: It comes as byte format. So im trying to pass it to a string and then using json,sump. I will update the code

Comment: So it's JSON format?

Comment: Yes is a json format.

Comment: That information should be in the question. Or, rather, since there's no way you can't find out how to parse JSON in Python, you don't have a problem with parsing the string and the question should just be about the data you got from parsing the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you left off the last `]` character. With the addition of that, you have a valid json string. You can just parse it and grab the things you want. Here I am assuming you want the strings from the lists:

```
import json

s = "\n[[[\"guns\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"china chinese spy balloon\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"aris hampers grand rapids\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"mountain lion p 22\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"real estate housing market\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"hunter biden\",46,[143,362,396,357],{\"lm\":[],\"zf\":33,\"zh\":\"Hunter Biden\",\"zi\":\"American attorney\",\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ssp\":\"eJzj4tLP1TcwycrOK88xYPTiySjNK0ktUkjKTEnNAwBulQip\"},\"zs\":\"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\\u003dtbn:ANd9GcQaO4eyFc6sDCa7A26Y_9g71clgC0Ot11Elt0KxAFiQo0Ey7Tp69FWxS8o\\u0026s\\u003d10\"}],[\"maui firefighter tre evans dumaran\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"pope francis benedict\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"coast guard rescue stolen boat\",0,[143,362,396,357],{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ss\":\"1\"}}],[\"lauren boebert\",46,[143,362,396,357],{\"lm\":[],\"zf\":33,\"zh\":\"Lauren Boebert\",\"zi\":\"United States Representative\",\"zl\":8,\"zp\":{\"gs_ssp\":\"eJzj4tVP1zc0zDIqMzCrMCswYPTiy0ksLUrNU0jKT01KLSoBAJDsCeg\"},\"zs\":\"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\\u003dtbn:ANd9GcS1qLJyZQJkVxsOTuP4gnADPLG5oBWe0LWSFClElzhcVrwVCfnNa_s64Zs\\u0026s\\u003d10\"}]],{\"ag\":{\"a\":{\"8\":[\"Trending searches\"]}}}]"

obj = json.loads(s)

def get_strings(item):
    if isinstance(item, str):
        yield item
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        for subitem in item:
            yield from get_strings(subitem)
            
list(get_strings(obj))
```

This will give you:

```
['guns',
 'china chinese spy balloon',
 'aris hampers grand rapids',
 'mountain lion p 22',
 'real estate housing market',
 'hunter biden',
 'maui firefighter tre evans dumaran',
 'pope francis benedict',
 'coast guard rescue stolen boat',
 'lauren boebert']
```

This assumes there's nothing you want in those dictionaries (like: `{\"zf\":33,\"zl\":8,\"zp\"`). If there is, it's simple enough to add another clause to deal with them, but you will need to figure out which text is junk and what is real (it all looked like junk to me).